# Preserve client IP in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have a backend application behind an nginx ingress controller in a GKE cluster and I want to whitelist a certain IP only to access it. I added to the associated ingress this annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "my-ip/32"
```

I also have the `externalTrafficPolicy` set to `Local` in the ingress controller service.

The issue is that when I hit my application it always return `403 Forbidden`
And in the ingress controller logs when I hit the application it logs `access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: my-appliaction.domain.ext` which means that the client IP is not forwarded to the ingress controller. I am using GCP GKE.

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
  enable-real-ip: "true"
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: "<pods_cidr>,<services_cidr>,<load_balance_ip>/32"
  use-proxy-protocol: "false"
```

And added the statement `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` on [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) Service that assign the load balance:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
    - appProtocol: https
      name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: <load_balance_ip>
```

Then, I also configured *ip-masq-agent* with the follow ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ip-masq-agent
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  config: |
    nonMasqueradeCIDRs:
      - <load_balance_ip>/32
      - <pods_cidr>
      - <services_cidr>
    masqLinkLocal: false
    resyncInterval: 30s
```

So, I deleted the DaemonSet *ip-masq-agent* and [gke](/questions/tagged/gke) automatic recreated it.

After that, I got my [gke](/questions/tagged/gke) cluster working as expected. And used with success `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` on Ingress.

You can find more information about *ip-masq-agent* on [gke](/questions/tagged/gke) accessing https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent